# How to fetch the sum of time of each delivery from array?

Tags: php

This script is written to fetch the sum of time of each `delivery` from array.
Currently output is wrong. Each `items` sum is listing.
`Eg 00:10:00, 00:25:00, 00:37:00`.
May be extracting array is not correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Code, Expecting Result and Array are given below.

delivery: `(delivery-id-1, delivery-id-2, delivery-id-3, etc)`:- It contains orders and items.

items: `(item-id-1, item-id-2)`:- It contains time.

**Expecting Result:**

Output of `delivery-id-1 (Total Time 00:42:00)-> 00:10:00, 00:15:00, 00:12:00, 00:02:00, 00:03:00`

Output of `delivery-id-2 (Total Time 00:35:00)-> 00:05:00, 00:20:00, 00:10:00`

**demo.php**

```
$deliveryResult = "array getting from other source";

$sum = strtotime('00:00:00');

$totaltime = 0;

foreach ($deliveryResult as $deliveryIdKey => $lineNumbersData)
{
  foreach ($lineNumbersData as $lineNumberKey => $itemsData)
  {
    foreach ($itemsData as $itemsDataKey => $item)
    {
      foreach ($item as $itemDataKey => $itemData)
      {
        $timeinsec = strtotime($itemData[1]) - $sum;
        $totaltime = $totaltime + $timeinsec;
        $h = intval($totaltime / 3600);
        $totaltime = $totaltime - ($h * 3600);
        $m = intval($totaltime / 60);
        $s = $totaltime - ($m * 60);
        
        echo("$h:$m:$s");
        // 00:10:00, 00:25:00, 00:37:00
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

**Array**

```
Array
    (
     [delivery-id-1] => Array
       (
         [order-id-1] => Array
           (
             [item-id-1] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => S
                       [1] => 00:10:00 
                     )
                 [1] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => M
                       [1] => 00:15:00 
                     )
               ) 
           )
         [order-id-2] => Array
           (
             [item-id-2] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => S
                       [1] => 00:12:00 
                     )
               ) 
           )
         [order-id-3] => Array
           (
             [item-id-3] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => L
                       [1] => 00:02:00 
                     )
               ) 
           )  
         [order-id-4] => Array
           (
             [item-id-4] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => K
                       [1] => 00:03:00 
                     )
               ) 
           )
       )

     [delivery-id-2] => Array
       (
         [order-id-5] => Array
           (
             [item-id-8] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => F
                       [1] => 00:05:00 
                     )
               )
           )
         [order-id-6] => Array
           (
             [item-id-9] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                      [0] => K
                      [1] => 00:20:00 
                     )
               ) 
           )
         [order-id-7] => Array
           (
             [item-id-1] => Array
               (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                      [0] => T
                      [1] => 00:10:00 
                     )
               ) 
           )  
       )
    )
```

**json encoded array**

```
{ 
 "delivery-id-1": {
     "order-id-1": {
        "item-id-1": [
          [
            "S",
            "00:10:00"
          ],
          [
            "M",
            "00:15:00"
          ]
        ]
     },
     "order-id-2": {
        "item-id-2": [
          [
            "S",
            "00:12:00"
          ]
        ]
     },
     "order-id-3": {
        "item-id-3": [
          [
            "L",
            "00:02:00"
          ]
        ]
     },
     "order-id-4": {
        "item-id-4": [
          [
            "K",
            "00:03:00"
          ]
        ]
     }
  },
  "delivery-id-2": {
    "order-id-5": {
       "item-id-8": [
         [
           "F",
           "00:05:00"
         ]
       ]
    },
    "order-id-6": {
        "item-id-9": [
          [
            "K",
            "00:20:00"
          ]
        ]
    },
    "order-id-7": {
        "item-id-1": [
          [
            "T",
            "00:10:00"
          ]
        ]
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: don't you mean `$itemData[1]` instead of `$itemData[2]` ? Also, could you post the json representation of the input array?

Comment: No. $itemData[2] is time. For example: if `delivery-id-1` then  `$itemData[2]` is `00:10:00, 00:15:00, 00:12:00, 00:02:00, 00:03:00`.

Comment: Regarding json data: This array is prepared base on multiple json files. For getting time the json format is `"data": [{"item_id": "item-id-1", "time": "00:10:00","quantity": 1},`

Comment: It looks like `$itemData[0]` is a letter, and `$itemData[1]` looks like the time to me. Can you `json_encode` the entire array and add that to your post?

Comment: @IT goldman Sorry, you are correct $itemData[1] is time. I have added json encoded array.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? That's so little code that even `vardump` could help to check what the variables contain, if you want to avoid using a proper debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a loop inside another and another. Stay on top using a good naming of variables. To combine the times I convert to seconds (much like you have).

```php
foreach ($deliveryResult as $delivery_key => $delivery) {
    $times = [];
    foreach ($delivery as $orders) {
        foreach ($orders as $items) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $times[] = $item[1];
            }

        }
    }
    $total_sec = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        $arr = explode(":", $time);
        $total_sec += (int) $arr[0] * 3600 + (int) $arr[1] * 60 + (int) $arr[2];
    }
    $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($total_sec / 3600), ($total_sec / 60 % 60), $total_sec % 60);
    echo ("Delivery $delivery_key: total $time (" . implode(", ", $times) . ") <br>");
}

/*
output:
Delivery delivery-id-1: total 00:42:00 (00:10:00, 00:15:00, 00:12:00, 00:02:00, 00:03:00)
Delivery delivery-id-2: total 00:35:00 (00:05:00, 00:20:00, 00:10:00)
*/
```